# Is there a CSS equivalent for the HTML <style media="screen">

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am a begginer in HTML and CSS, and I am wondering if there is an equivalent of `<style media="screen"></style>` for .css files ?
I have my main HTML that call :

```
<style media="screen">
    .bg-red{
        background: red;
</style>
```

I am trying to add this part in my *style.css* file. I tryed to add `@media` properties, but did not succeed, and don't see my mistakes.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px){
    .bg-red{
        background: red;
    }
}
```

And

```
@media screen {
    .bg-red{
        background: red;
    }
}
```

I tried min-width, max-width, etc but without results.

Thank you for your advice !

Here is my code:
https://codepen.io/arthurdraws/pen/gOYJwRL

```css
body, html{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.btn {
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 4rem;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 5rem;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:hover{
  background-color: red;
}
p{
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- animsition.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/animsition@latest/dist/css/animsition.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- animsition.js -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/animsition@latest/dist/js/animsition.min.js"></script>
    <style media="screen">
      .bg-red{
        background: red;
      }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is a test page</h1>

 <div class="animsition-layer" data-animsition-overlay="true">
    <a href="#" class="animsition-link btn" data-animsition-out-class="overlay-slide-out-left bg-red" data-animsition-out-duration="300">
      Button
   </a>
  </div>

  <p>How to transfer the "style media="screen" { .bg-red{background: red} }" from my HTML sample to my CSS file ?
  </p>



<script>
 // OVERLAY
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".animsition-layer").animsition({
            inClass: 'overlay-slide-in-top',
            inDuration: 0,
            outDuration: 420,
            linkElement: '.animsition-link',
            loading: false,
            loadingClass: 'animsition-loading',
            loadingInner: '',
            timeout: false,
            timeoutCountdown: 5000,
            onLoadEvent: true,
            browser: [ 'animation-duration', '-webkit-animation-duration'],
            overlay : true,
            overlayClass : 'animsition-overlay-slide',
            overlayParentElement : 'body',
            transition: function(url){ window.location.href = url; }
        })
    });

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `@media screen {` should be sufficient? A quick googling gave me this page: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Unfortunately no, it doesn't works for my case...
I am wondering if the problem is from the <div> I call the bg-red or not

Comment: The CSS rule works just fine, it's just that the CSS file is in a different position on the page so another rule overrides the background color rule. Try a more specific rule like `@media screen { .animsition-overlay-slide.bg-red { background: red; } }` and you'll see the red background.

Comment: So which tag actually includes ‘class=“bg-red”’?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to increase the specifity of your selector :

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity
>
> Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be applied. Specificity is based on the matching rules which are composed of different sorts of CSS selectors.

```
@media screen {
      body > .bg-red{
        background: red;
      }
}
```

Snippet demo below :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".animsition-layer").animsition({
    inClass: 'overlay-slide-in-top',
    inDuration: 0,
    outDuration: 420,
    linkElement: '.animsition-link',
    loading: false,
    loadingClass: 'animsition-loading',
    loadingInner: '',
    timeout: false,
    timeoutCountdown: 5000,
    onLoadEvent: true,
    browser: ['animation-duration', '-webkit-animation-duration'],
    overlay: true,
    overlayClass: 'animsition-overlay-slide',
    overlayParentElement: 'body',
    transition: function(url) {
      window.location.href = url;
    }
  })
});
```

```css
@media screen {
  body>.bg-red {
    background: red;
  }
}

body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 4rem;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 5rem;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

p {
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- animsition.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/animsition@latest/dist/css/animsition.min.css">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- animsition.js -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/animsition@latest/dist/js/animsition.min.js"></script>

<h1>This is a test page</h1>

<div class="animsition-layer" data-animsition-overlay="true">
  <a href="#" class="animsition-link btn" data-animsition-out-class="overlay-slide-out-left bg-red" data-animsition-out-duration="300">
      Button
   </a>
</div>

<p>How to transfer the "style media="screen" { .bg-red{background: red} }" from my HTML sample to my CSS file ?
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the link to have .bg-red, then you need to add it to the `class` attribute instead of your `data-animsition-out-class`.

```
@media screen {
  .bg-red: {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

<a href="#" class="animsition-link btn bg-red" data-animsition-out-class="overlay-slide-out-left" data-animsition-out-duration="300">
```

Comment: Why a downvote here , when bg-red is actually, as said, not inside the class attribute, .bg-red in the CSS file matches no class of that name

Comment: The JS library adds the classes in the data attribute when the button is clicked. Anyway this wouldn't explain why the embedded style works but a rule in a separate CSS file doesn't.

Comment: @JJJ then it does  work , and there is no question anymore, open the codepen provided by the op  and click the button https://codepen.io/arthurdraws/pen/gOYJwRL

Comment: @G-Cyr The codepen is the working version. The OP wants to know why it stops working when they use media queries instead.

Comment: @jjj , okay , oups , then there is a question

Comment: Exactly, I have closed the topic, I needed to add *body > .bg-red*
I wanted the overlay to be red, via *media = screen*